# Simulate outcome with adjusted regression models

Tags: python, r, regression

I have a question concerning regression models.

Let's assume I have three companies called A, B and C.
The goal is to compare the companies with respect to the salary they pay to their employees. For the features we use: age, education, experience and internship. internship and education are categorical variables. For each company I have roughly 100 samples/datapoints.

(27 years old, 5 years experience, education diploma, ..., salary 60 000)

So, now back to the problem. I want to predict salary for the three different companies. Let us assume company B pays much less regarding the education, cause education levels are maybe not comparable across the companies.

So, I want to adjust or normalize for education. That means I want to use an overall regression coefficient for education for each company, but I want to keep the other coeffs separately.

OK, I could do this with interaction terms. e.g.

salary ~ education + age:company + ...

this works for education, but to reduce the overall mse some coeffs get weird results. Actually, I want to simulate the salary afterwards to show, that neglecting or better adjusting/normalizing for education, company B pays best.
This does not work with the approach above.

Another way I tried was using mixedModels. Cause somehow there is another level. The level Company. But I have heard that this is not the correct approach for only three levels. Do you know any better idea?

The third way was a brute force method. We fit three models, one for each company. Afterwards, we modify the education coeff and replace it with a weighted mean of all models. And then we make prediction with these modified models. However, I don't know if this is a valid approach. And I have many more variables I want to "adjust for".

So, to sum up: I want to use a group effect of some variables, and an individual effect of some other variables. And afterwards I wanna make new predictions to compare the target means.

Sorry for my weird writing here. I hope someone can help.

Comment: First, this sounds like a question for [stats.se] not here. Second, it sounds as if you are unhappy with the results of your interaction term and are looking for new methods to give you a different answer. This is bad and indeed dishonest statistics! (Maybe I am wrong and you have something else in mind by "This does not work with the approach above"... if so, edit your question to clarify. But in any case, migrate to [stats.se])

Comment: It seems the concepts of confounding and interaction got mixed up here. If com B pays less on average because they hired people with less education (and education is positively correlated with income), that's confounding, and can be simulated by setting the coefficient for company indicator. If com B values education less (aka, for each year in additional education the payment increase is lower than com A), that's interaction, and you'll need to fit those interaction terms separately.

Comment: Hello,thanks for the migration.
@ dash: What I want is to fir separate models for each company to get coefficients for e.g. age, education, etc. Afterwards I want to combine the models and use something like the mean effect of age over the models but keep the education coefficients. So, combing age_A, age_B, age_C to age, but keeping edu_A, edu_B, edu_C. In this way I can simulate new salaries as if the companies would all pay the same with respect to age. But I don't know how to build such a model.